# Java search string for certain wordgroups

Tags: java, html, search

I have this code, which is working fine, that is giving me the source code of a website:

```
package Quellenpackage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
public class Quellcode {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final String meineURL = "http://www.onvista.de/aktien/technische-kennzahlen/Aareal-Bank-Aktie-DE0005408116";

            URL url = new URL(meineURL);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            // read complete content


            String line ="";
            String code ="";

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                code += line + "\r\n";
            }

            // open Reader
            br.close();
            isr.close();


            // give out page content

            System.out.println(code);

            }
```

At the moment, this shows me the whole code of the page, but I only want a certain part.
This part should be exactly between this exact signs `"Start:"` and `"ende"`. So I need something that searches the code for the.. "Start:"
.. part and then gives out everything until the "ende"

I have absolutely no clue whatsoever if this is possible let alone know how to do it. I really hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Your code doesn't return to me sting with `Start:` but `Startseite`. Also there is no separate `ende` word but many words containing it like `render` or `Gleitende`.

Comment: I know I chose those just for an example, because I kept getting the same error of stackoverflow for the html code I actually wanted to write down here. Those are just two random words to make my question more clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `String.split()` method see doku [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Its seperates a `String` into different Strings at any time the given paremeter is found somewhere in the string.

```
String[] parts = code.split("Start:"); //makes to parts before Start: and after Start:
parts = parts[1].split("ende"); //makes to parts before ende and after ende
String result = parts[0]; //here is the result
```

### Problem with more than one `ende`:

If there are more than one `ende` in the code it wont work this way so you have to choose a different solution where you add the other parts back in:

```
String[] parts = code.split("Start:");
parts = parts[1].split("ende");
String result = parts[0];
//special case:
//add every splitted sub string, but NOT the last one
for (int i = 1;i<parts.length-1;i++){
  result+=parts[i];
}
```